# C# Webclient is very slow on first request

Tags: c#, performance, webclient

I know this has been asked before, but I have spend the last 2 hours trying solutions (found through Google) without any positive results.

The solution I found was: setting the 'webclient.proxy' to 'null', but that doesn't have much impact on the first request, unfortunately.

Is there any other solution, besides doing a dummy request at runtime, to make it (my official request) complete faster?

Comment: Why not just use `HttpClient`? It's recommended over `WebClient`

Answer (score 4):

Webclient has a few areas which can potentially be slow, but not always WebClients fault

1. DNS Lookup - If your using a local DNS or even a remote DNS with a slow lookup or split dns, then it is entirely possible that the initial DNS hit is taking a time, after which point the DNS would be cached.
2. Test remote end, certain webservers and webapps take longer to answer on their first request after a certain amount of time (Just try a non pre-compiled IIS Process with no one using it for a few hours and you'll see what I mean). To rule this out, attempt request the URL by hand first to see if it speeds the WebClient Up.
3. Run a HTTP sniffer. Something like [`Fiddler`](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) where you can see when the initial request happens, when the request is made, the time to first byte and transfer time. This will help you see if the problem lies with your application, with your network stack or further afield.